# How to resolve the chef error "can not find a plugin for dependency linux::network"?

Tags: chef, ruby

There are no google hits for this error message.

I am attempting to run chef-client on a server that has run it successfully in the past. I do not know what changed to produce this error. Here is the most verbose output I can think to include:

```
> chef-client -l debug
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] DEBUG: Fork successful. Waiting for new chef pid: 17823
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] DEBUG: Forked instance now converging
Starting Chef Client, version 11.16.4
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.16.4 ***
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 17823
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] DEBUG: Chef-client request_id: 8ebe3de0-1e0a-4647-b2bb-d48aa020b815
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] WARN: [DEPRECATION] Plugin at /etc/chef/ohai_plugins/dpkg.rb is a version 6 plugin. Version 6 plugins will not be supported in future releases of Ohai. Please upgrade your plugin to version 7 plugin syntax. For more information visit here: docs.opscode.com/ohai_custom.html
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] WARN: [DEPRECATION] Plugin at /etc/chef/ohai_plugins/network_addr.rb is a version 6 plugin. Version 6 plugins will not be supported in future releases of Ohai. Please upgrade your plugin to version 7 plugin syntax. For more information visit here: docs.opscode.com/ohai_custom.html
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] WARN: [DEPRECATION] Plugin at /etc/chef/ohai_plugins/ipmi.rb is a version 6 plugin. Version 6 plugins will not be supported in future releases of Ohai. Please upgrade your plugin to version 7 plugin syntax. For more information visit here: docs.opscode.com/ohai_custom.html
[2014-10-09T17:50:19-05:00] DEBUG: Skipping provides 'linux/dpkg' for plugin 'dpkg'
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] DEBUG: Skipping provides 'network' for plugin 'network_addr'
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] DEBUG: Can not find any v7 plugin that provides linux/network
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Ohai::Exceptions::DependencyNotFound - Can not find a plugin for dependency linux::network
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:55:in `require_plugin'
  (eval):21:in `block in collect_contents'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:47:in `block in collect_contents'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin.rb:98:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin.rb:169:in `safe_run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/runner.rb:59:in `run_v6_plugin'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/runner.rb:45:in `run_plugin'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:83:in `block in run_plugins'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:82:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:82:in `run_plugins'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:73:in `all_plugins'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:292:in `run_ohai'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:414:in `do_run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/cache/chef/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] DEBUG: Ohai::Exceptions::DependencyNotFound: Can not find a plugin for dependency linux::network
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:55:in `require_plugin'
(eval):21:in `block in collect_contents'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin/versionvi.rb:47:in `block in collect_contents'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin.rb:98:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin.rb:169:in `safe_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/runner.rb:59:in `run_v6_plugin'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/runner.rb:45:in `run_plugin'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:83:in `block in run_plugins'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:82:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:82:in `run_plugins'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ohai-7.4.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:73:in `all_plugins'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:292:in `run_ohai'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:414:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 0.66186153 seconds
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] ERROR: Can not find a plugin for dependency linux::network
[2014-10-09T17:50:20-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I tried updating my chef from 11.16.0 to 11.16.4, from .deb packages from getchef.com, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are attempting to load some Ohai plugins, typically to augment the current data that is provided by the default Ohai plugin.

Here's the things that I would do:

1. Inspect any custom Ohai plugins for a dependency on either `linux::network` or `linux/network` - since this is the namespace something is looking for. Probably anything in `/etc/chef/ohai_plugins/*.rb` is a good candidate to start with.
2. Inspect any recipe code looking for `linux::network` and read where that attribute is meant to come from, since the default Ohai namespace is `network` and can be seen via `sudo ohai network`.

Again, this is not a default Ohai namespace, so either another plugin is attempting to provide the details incorrectly, or a recipe in incorrectly looking to reference them. The former is more likely.